# How to redirect contact form to thank you page

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, redirect, contacts

I am working with a premium Wordpress Theme and I am trying to get the custom contact form that came with the theme to redirect to a thank you page after successful completion (this is for conversion tracking purposes)

Anyways here is the code that calls the shortcode when entered on a page

```
    add_shortcode('etheme_contacts', 'etheme_contacts_shortcodes');
    function etheme_contacts_shortcodes($atts, $content=null){
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
       'gmap' => 1
    ), $atts );
    if(isset($_GET['contactSubmit'])){
    $emailFrom = strip_tags($_GET['contactEmail']);
    $emailTo = etheme_get_option('contacts_email');
    $subject = strip_tags($_GET['contactSubject']);

    $name = strip_tags($_GET['contactName']); 
    $email = strip_tags($_GET['contactEmail']); 
    $message = strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['contactMessage'])); 

    $body = "Name: ".$name."\n";
    $body .= "Email: ".$email."\n";
    $body .= "Message: ".$message."\n";
    $body .= $name.", <b>".$emailFrom."</b>\n";

    $headers = "From: ".$emailFrom."\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To:".$emailFrom."\n";    

    if(isset($_GET['contactSubmit'])){
        $success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        if ($success){
        echo '<p class="yay">All is well, your e&ndash;mail has been sent.</p>';
        } 
    } else {
        echo '<p class="oops">Something went wrong</p>';
    }
    } else {
    if($a['gmap'] == 1):
    ?>

    <div id="map">
        <p>Enable your JavaScript!</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $map = jQuery('#map');    
        if( $map.length ) {    
            $map.gMap({
                address: '<?php etheme_option('google_map'); ?>',
                zoom: 16,
                markers: [
                    { 'address' : '<?php etheme_option('google_map'); ?>' }
                ]
            });    
        }  
        var succmsg = '<?php _e('All is well, your e&ndash;mail has been sent!',     ETHEME_DOMAIN); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(etheme_option('contacts_custom_html') != ''): ?>
    <div class="custom-html">
        <?php echo etheme_option('contacts_custom_html') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="one-third">      
        <div id="contactsMsgs"></div>  
        <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="POST" class="form"      id="ethemeContactForm">   
            <div class="formField">
                <label for="contactName"><?php _e('Name', ETHEME_DOMAIN); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="textField required-field" name="contactName" id="contactName" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formField">
                <label for="contactEmail"><?php _e('Email', ETHEME_DOMAIN); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="textField required-field email" name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formField">
                <label for="contactSubject"><?php _e('Subject', ETHEME_DOMAIN); ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="textField" name="contactSubject" id="contactSubject" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formField">
                <label for="contactMessage"><?php _e('Message', ETHEME_DOMAIN); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <textarea class="textField required-field" name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="formField ">
                <button class="button" name="contactSubmit" type="submit"><span><?php _e('Send Request', ETHEME_DOMAIN); ?></span></button>
                <div class="contactSpinner"></div>
            </div>
        </form>      
    </div>
    <div class="one-third last fl-r">
        <div class="block non-line contats">
            <?php etheme_option('contacts_info'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
}
```

I am assuming that there is something that needs to be changed here because this is where the php sets a function for the form being submitted but because of my noobness I am not sure what to do with this code.

```
if(isset($_GET['contactSubmit'])){
$success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
if ($success){
echo '<p class="yay">All is well, your e&ndash;mail has been sent.</p>';
} 
} else {
echo '<p class="oops">Something went wrong</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/thanyk_you.html' ) ;
```

replacing the current:

```
echo '<p class="yay">All is well, your mail has been sent.</p>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put your desired URL in the Additional Settings box

> on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"

Remember you should include footer function in footer.php, otherwise it will not work.

Second solution is to change the coding in plugin file.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Theres several solutions here, but the one with the least amount of typing goes like this:

1. Make a thank you page (in wordpress) and grab the url
2. replace the succes echo line with `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://stackoverflow.com'>` or `header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;` with your url instead of the stackoverflow one.
3. Do the same for the echo line for something that went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since your working with Wordpress id recommend the built in wp_redirect();

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

```
if(isset($_GET['contactSubmit'])){
   $success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
   if ($success){
     //comment out below...
     //echo '<p class="yay">All is well, your e&ndash;mail has been sent.</p>';
     wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/your-thank-you-page/');
     exit;
   } 
} else {
  echo '<p class="oops">Something went wrong</p>';
}
```